# Collatz Conjecture in Python for N inputs

Tags: python

This is my first time using Stack Overflow. I will try my best to be as clear as I can be. I need to write a code that returns my initial number, the number of even values, the number of odd values and the biggest value for each N I input. My issue with this is: I have at least two entries: N, number of values my program will receive, and X, the number itself (for N = 1, for example). When I finished my code, I noticed that for N > 1 the number of even and odd numbers are stacking, but the biggest number for each sequence is correct.

For N = 2, X = 9 and X = 15, the output is:

```
Initial value: 9
Even numbers: 13
Odd numbers: 7
Biggest number: 52

Initial value: 15
Even numbers: 25
Odd numbers: 13
Biggest number: 160
```

Any idea of why this is happening? Here is my code:

```
N = int(input())
EVEN = 0
ODD = 0

for i in range(N):
    X = int(input())
    print("Initial value: ", X)
    MAX = X
    while = True
        if X % 2 == 0:
           EVEN = EVEN + 1
           X = X / 2
        elif X == 1:
           ODD = ODD + 1
           break

        elif X % 2 == 1:
           ODD = ODD + 1
           X = (3 * X) + 1
           if X > MAX
                MAX = X

    print("Even numbers: ", EVEN)
    print("Odd numbers: ", ODD)
    print("Biggest number: ", MAX)
```

Comment: You need to RESET the EVEN/ODD inside the loop ... currently you set it to 0 on the outside so it never gets reset to 0 after you finished for one input. so `for i in range(N):EVEN=0;ODD=0;while True: .... etc`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you forgot to reset the `even`/`odd` counters at every step of the for loop. It should work like this:

```
...
for i in range(N):
    EVEN = 0
    ODD = 0
    X = int(input())
    print("Initial value: ", X)
    MAX = X
    while True:
        ...
```